# Spring boot with Apache CXF Multipart request always fails with 400

Tags: spring-boot, cxf

I am using spring boot along with Apache CXF. My REST API definition looks as below

```
@PUT
@Consumes(value = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@ApiOperation(value = "Sends a notification")
public boolean sendNotification(
@FormParam(QueryParams.SUBJECT) String subject,
@FormParam(QueryParams.MESSAGE) String message) {

}
```

---

When we hit via REST client, we are always getting 400.

```
PUT /rest/notifications HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9080
User-Agent: insomnia/2020.3.3
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
Accept: /
Content-Length: 231

--X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"
A new topic has been created
--X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"
A new topic has been created
--X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY--
We are completely uploaded and fine
Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
HTTP/1.1 400 
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2020 05:08:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 50
Connection: close
```

Comment: You need to send both SUBJECT and MESSAGE to this endpoint. Otherwise you will get 400 http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html#JAX-RSMultiparts-MultipartannotationandOptionalattachments

Comment: Its a multipart request and contains both subject/message parts.